# What alignment would the Ancient Roman civilisation have been?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e, world-building, alignment

In our Pathfinder homebrew setting, I'm looking at making a region that borrows parts of the culture of Ancient Rome, including their system of slavery.

What alignment would the Ancient Roman nation have been classified as, under a typical D&D 3.5/Pathfinder alignment system?

Specifically, the period of Roman history I'm referring to is during the period of Roman imperial expansion. The aspects of slavery I am mostly looking at are the myriad professions (teacher, miner, doctor, servant, etc.), manumission, freedmen bureaucrats, and potentially gladiatoral/circus exhibitions.

Comment: You'll have to be specific about which RPG system you're using here. If it's some edition of Dungeons & Dragons, which version is it? Not all D&D editions share the same alignment system.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited a clarification. I didn't realise 4e had changed the system.

Comment: In general you need to be specific about the system too, since D&D is only one of several *thousand*. Thanks for that edit. Also, 3.5e itself is different to some of the earlier editions!

Comment: Which period of the Roman empire are you thinking of, specifically? The political and social organisation of the empire changed repeatedly and significantly over its duration. Also, the empire embraced multiple traditions of slavery - was there any particular one you had in mind?

Comment: During the period of Roman imperial expansion. The aspects of slavery I was mostly looking at were the myriad professions (teacher, miner, doctor, servant, etc.), manumission, freedmen bureaucrats, and potentially gladiatoral/circus exhibitions.

Comment: It also helps to speak about regions. And *which* era of expansion. Rome is a *huge historical monster*. I've closed this as opinion based as anyone should be able to cherry-pick elements from expansionist roman history that support their chosen alignment claim. Please give us a year and region.